# Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.0 doesn´t work with sybase database

Tags: 16.04, database, php7

This package offers the function to manipulate a sybase database, but doesn´t provide a `sybase_connect` PHP function.

The package was installed:

```
renato@webv3:/var/www/html$ aptitude show php-sybase
Pacote: php-sybase
Estado: instalado
Automaticamente instalado: não
Versão: 1:7.0+35ubuntu6
Prioridade: opcional
Seção: universe/php
Mantenedor: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Arquitetura: all
Tamanho Descompactado: 11,3 k
Depende de: php-common, php7.0-sybase
Descrição: Sybase module for PHP [default]
 This package provides a Sybase module for PHP.
```

the test code

```
<?php
$link = sybase_connect('SYBASE', '', '')
        or die("Could not connect !");
echo "Connected successfully";
sybase_close($link);
?>
```

shows error below

```
[Thu Jun 23 17:20:49.100056 2016] [:error] [pid 5188] [client x.x.x.x:55770] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sybase_connect() in /var/www/html/info2.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/info2.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sybase_connect()` function was **removed** in PHP 7.0.0.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sybase-connect.php

An answer was posted on Stack Overflow: [PHP7 - Connect to sybase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890610/php7-connect-to-sybase-database)